# Linking to a non https page from https relative path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http, https

May this be the stupidest question ever, sorry if so, but I cannot figure it out:

I have in my HTTPS page:

```
<a href="../../../folder/index.php?openMenu=SEARCH">Advanced searh</a>
```

And this would work but the link points to a HTTP page (not S).

So when I click on the Advanced search link, I go to the right place but for the https that should be http and therefore I get a page not found.

Is there anything PHP/javascript/jquery I can do to avoid this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **can't** be achieved without using absolute URL.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654427/1856120

Take a look at phpUri:

```
phpUri::parse("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]")->join('../../relative-path') // HTTP link;

phpUri::parse("https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]")->join('../../relative-path') // HTTPS link;
```

https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri

Or using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444490/1856120